# Is there a way to get a set of 'child list' in sharepoint; i.e., lists that contains a lookup field to a given list?

Tags: list, lookup-column

This is what I have so far. It seems to work, but is very slow since its traversing all lists and fields in the site. Note: I am looking for the first list that shows up as a 'child list':

```
private SPList GetChildList(SPList list)
    {
        SPList childList = null;

        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://dev01/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)
            {
                foreach (SPList relatedList in spWeb.Lists)
                {
                    foreach (SPField field in relatedList.Fields)
                    {
                        if (field.Type == SPFieldType.Lookup && field.InternalName.Contains("SomeFieldName"))
                        {
                            SPFieldLookup lookupField = field as SPFieldLookup;
                            if (list.RootFolder.Name == spWeb.Lists[new Guid(lookupField.LookupList)].RootFolder.Name)
                            {
                                return relatedList;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return childList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could iterate through site fields, instead of lists, and foreach LookupField check its ListsFieldUsedIn method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listsfieldusedin.aspx